# Intel 82574L Gigabit NIC - WoL option missing in driver settings?

Tags: drivers, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

I have an Intel 82574L Gigabit NIC which I am trying to configure to use with Wake on LAN.

In the driver settings for this NIC, there are no options corresponding to Wake on LAN.

I'm running Windows 10 (x64) and have the latest driver from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/32210/Intel-82574-Gigabit-Ethernet-Controller).

So far, I've tried installing drivers for other OS's from that download page, but 8.1, 8, 7 and XP were all rejected.

Was WoL support removed from the driver for this model? Do I need to install the NIC driver for a completely different Intel NIC?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same exact issue as you with the Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit, and could not get my Windows 10 install to show the wake on lan magic packet option in the driver advanced page. I'm a dual windows/ubuntu user so i looked on my Ubuntu ethtool utility and found out that the wake on lan had already been set to enabled. With this i used a wake_on_lan utility on my phone and sure enough it was able to send a magic packet and turn on the server instantly.

Since this is a PCI card we dont need to find a wakeonlan option in BIOS/UEFI unless you plan to use the onboard nic.

If you want to check to see if the magic packet flag is set on the NIC card, and you have basic UNIX/Linux knowledge you can load up a live boot of ubuntu or whichever distro and use the "ethtool" utility to see and also set the g flag (magic packet) to the nic.

You can test all this on a home network using a wakeonlan phone app with the MAC address of the supported device.

```
lspci | grep -i ethernet

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

```
ethtool <nic>
```

```
ex.
Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

The 'g' in Supports Wake-on: pumbg indicates that wake-on-lan by using a 'magic packet' is indeed supported.

Let me know if this helps. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Please search old windows driver.

ex)
Intel 82574L lenovo

It was a driver for windows server from lenovo site.
I install successfully on windows 11(not a lenovo machine).

WOL works fine.